# sed match pattern \tTEXT\t not working

Tags: regex, bash, sed, text-processing

I use the following command on a huge text file

```
sed 's/\tEN-GB\t//g' "/home/ubuntu/0214/corpus/C.txt"
```

The file contains a [tab]EN-GB[tab] in each row, but what I get is the original text. I cannot figure out why. 
**NOTE:** when I'm using 's/\t//g' it works and the resulting string is [a lot of no-tabs]EN-GB[a lot of no-tabs] in each row, so the tabs vanished.

UPDATE: Here is the incriminated part of the output from cat -vet:

```
^@2^@0^@0^@7^@0^@1^@0^@4^@~^@1^@6^@3^@2^@4^@3^@^I^@^I^@0^@^I^@E^@N^@-^@G^@B^@^I^@T^@h^@e^@      ^@a^@d^@m^@i^@n^@i^@s^@t^@
```

I'm out of black magic... thanks in advance

Comment: It is working fine to me. Are you sure it is tabs before and after `EN-GB`?

Comment: Yes. And behold:  's/\tE//g' works but 's/\tEN//g' does not. Seems like the two letters E and N are too much for him

Comment: Looks like you're on Ubuntu - what's the `sed` versionn (`sed --version`)? To rule out problems with `sed` itself, see if the following yields "[Col1][Col3]": `sed 's/\tEN-GB\t//g' <<<$'[Col1]\tEN-GB\t[Col3]'`

Comment: @mklement0 The OP doesn't seem to be using GNU sed.

Comment: @devnull: Given that the input file path contains `ubuntu`, I would expect it him to, though - unless a different sed was installed later. (The ANSI-C quoting, as in your answer, would be required on OSX, for instance, but it shouldn't be with GNU sed, and the OP says that the use of `\t` at least _partially_ works). Are there _old_ GNU sed versions that also didn't support control-char. escapes such as `\t`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu if this helps, and \t works, I can delete all tabs, even tab+'E', but not tab+'EN', which is magical

Comment: @ViktorPless Chances are that there is a stray character ahead of `E`.  Post the output of `cat -vet filename`.

Comment: Here's a part with the EN-GB
^@2^@0^@0^@7^@0^@1^@0^@4^@~^@1^@6^@3^@2^@4^@3^@^I^@^I^@0^@^I^@E^@N^@-^@G^@B^@^I^@T^@h^@e^@ ^@a^@d^@m^@i^@n^@i^@s^@t^@

Comment: @ViktorPless Please update the question with the requested information.  Comments are not quite suitable for such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ANSI-C quoting to represent the <kbd>TAB</kbd> character:

```
sed 's/'$'\tEN-GB\t''//g' filename
```

---

EDIT: The output of `cat -vet` suggests that you have NULL characters in your input.  Remove those before piping the results to the above command.  Say:

```
tr -d '\x0' < filename | sed 's/'$'\tEN-GB\t''//g'
```

Comment: This removes the tabs only, but I could do it anyway. what i needed was tab-text-tab

Comment: Thanks but no change :(

Comment: @ViktorPless You need to get rid of the null characters in the input; refer to the edit above.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your sed command is correct but you have some null characters in your text file

Run this sed command to remove nulls first:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\x0//g; s/\tEN-GB\t//g' "/home/ubuntu/0214/corpus/C.txt"
```

Comment: +1; it could be done in a single command, without a separate pass for preprocessing the input file: `sed 's/\x0//g; s/\tEN-GB\t//g' "/home/ubuntu/0214/corpus/C.txt"`.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks, Yes definitely it can be done in single sed command, let me edit.